# Installer hangs/get stuck at "where are you?"

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 alongside Windows 7. When I try to install this, the installer hangs at the screen where it asks "Where are you?". This screen has a forward button. Neither I can click on the forward button, nor can I type in the text box. But I can click and type in other places like the system settings Window. I can also move the windows, etc. The progress bar shows "copying files" and remains like that forever.

How can I get past this installation?

Comment: maybe another installation file?

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution [here in this bug report](http://fossplanet.com/f10/%5Bbug-772415%5D-%5Bnew%5D-ubuntu-11-04-hangs-waiting-timezone-window-142771/#post493607). Quoting the relevant part here:

> Hi,
>
> A new discovery! Today I tried again but this time DISCONECTING THE
>   NETWORK, and voila!. It let me choose the right TimeZone and carry on
>   with the installing process. In any case is still a problem because
>   the installer is not suppoused to wait forever in that place.
>
> Greetings.